# Communication between Cocoa and SWF using WebKit

Tags: flash, cocoa, webkit

I'm trying to implement a basic WebView containing a SWF file inside. The SWF file plays and apparently works fine. However I'd like to know if there's some way to retrieve an ActionScript variable from my Cocoa application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it via an intermediate JavaScript layer and ActionScript's ExternalInterface. ExternalInterface can be used against other host languages and Flash host containers, but I guess a JavaScript bridge is the most likely in a WebView.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html